# ipad - prevent scrolling past the end of the body content?

Tags: ipad, scroll

On my ipad version of my site, if I scroll down to the bottom of my page, it keeps scrolling till the end of the body is about halfway up the ipad screen, so the top of half of the ipad screen is the end of my content and the bottom half is the default ipad background (gray fabric style background).

Is there any way to disable this?

Comment: I doubt it. This is built into the OS itself. Much like how you can do this with apps too. Any reason why you want to disable it?

Comment: Should note, it does this with all websites including google.com, I'm sure this is an accessibility featured apple has, but it's inconvenient for websites that don't want this

Comment: I have a footer nav bar thats positioned static, one of the buttons are clicked it opens an overlay, so when half the viewport is not visible it kind of defeats the purpose of the overlay.

Comment: Because it's not the website itself you're seeing at that point, that's a part of the OS itself. It's just how the OS itself works. It shouldn't be making any effect or impact on the web app itself.